# What happens if a team kicks the ball through the uprights on a kickoff?

Tags: rules, american-football

What happens if during a kickoff, the kicker kicks the ball through the uprights?

These are the two situations I think this is possible:

1. The game kick-off
2. Kick after touchdown

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author did no research and this is a very basic rule in football.

Comment: Personally, I don't think it's the worst question - I certainly don't know the answer. I understand what you're saying about a lack of research, but if we applied that an awful lot of good questions would be excluded.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question. I've learnt something, so it's a worthwhile question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a common occurrence, especially in the NFL now that kickoffs have moved to the 35 yard line. But it does not result in points.

From the NFL rules (rule 3, section 10):

> **FIELD GOAL**
>     A Field Goal is made by kicking the ball from the field of play through the plane of the opponents' goal by a drop kick or a placekick either:
>   (a) From behind the line on a play from scrimmage; or
>   (b) During a fair catch kick. See 11-4-3; 3-9; and 10-2-4-a.

A kickoff is neither a play from scrimmage nor a fair catch kick (a fair catch kick can occur only immediately following a kick that was fair-caught). Therefore, kicking the ball through the uprights results merely in a touchback, just like kicking the ball out of any other part of the end zone would.